# Question/Resolved - "extra data after last expected column" Error when trying to import a csv file into postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, import-csv

Just posting this question and the solution since it took forever for me to figure this out.

Using CSV file, I was trying to import data into PostgreSQL with pgAdmin.  I kept running into the same issue of "extra data after last expected column."

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me (instead of using Import module): copy tablename (columns) FROM 'file location .csv' CSV HEADER

Since some of the data included multiple commas within the cell, it was counting as a new column each time.